# Detecting the changing areas in a web page

Tags: html, web-scraping, web-crawler

I'm trying to write a crawler that gets raw html data and finds Title, price, update date, photo etc... fields and writes it to database. This is an classic and old way to crawl data.

I think that I can do this job wit an other way.

If I crawl all pages (may be more than 1000) in the web site, and compare them all I can find the specific areas.

I mean html tags will be always the same. Only specific areas will change like title, image etc...

So, what is the best way to determine changed areas?

Comment: I tink, xml diff is not the correct answer because it compares two xml files. But I need a solution to compare 1000 pages.

Answer (score 0):

> compare them all I can find the spesific areas
>
> what is the best way to determine changed areas?

In your question you set the scrapeing/crawling approach of comparing pages' parts and getting the data of specific areas. This smells with regex approach. **Do not use it** as the very non-efficient approach. Rather **use xpath**, operating on XML structures.

So, be simple:

1. Get html
2. Make it DOM
3. Make DOM a valid XML
4. Apply xPath queries to XML

Believe me, xml libraries are well able to handle huge structures (including idle html tags) and traverse over them. A classical example of using xpath is in [this post](http://scraping.pro/using-domxpath-for-parsing-page-content-in-php/) of mine.

To determine data node paths you just use web inspector tools (F12 - in Chrome and IE and Ctrl+Shift+I in FF) to see the html tags containing useful info.